# How to place button inside of TextInput in Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I want to add button with image in TextInput Like in image bellow

[image]

Please suggest me the crystal clear way to do so!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired way to do this is to create custom component that extends the Flex `TextInput` Control. You can create a custom skin based on standard `TextInputSkin` and place icon in that skin.

[EDIT]

Not exactly what you want. But This may help you..

http://saturnboy.com/2010/07/supertextinput-building-a-custom-component/

Comment: See this tutorial: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JAc7Ih9KFGkU1V962WKgE1-1PDgFmgTMXcRnjkME31s/edit